# Copying existing password protected sheet to new workbook as an unprotected sheet does not make the new worksheet unprotected

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Copying an existing password protected sheet to a new workbook as an unprotected sheet gives the following error when user tries to type in data in the new worksheet.

> Error: "the cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet"

Click OK on the error message.

Please note that this error happens only once. click OK on the pop up error message and type again, then excel allows you to type data in the cells and save the sheet.

We have an excel (format .xls) file currently being used to create another excel spreadsheet when a button on a form in the same spreadsheet is clicked. It basically copies one password protected blank sheet (a template) to a new workbook as an unprotected sheet. The code below used to work with excel 2007(using .xls format). We recently upgraded from excel 2007 to excel 2013 and the problem appeared.

```
Private Sub cmd_Click()
Dim jBook As Workbook
Dim jsheet As Worksheet

CurrentWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Unprotect jWorksheetPassword
'catch all for errors
On Error GoTo ErrEnd  

Dim orginalScreenUpdating As Boolean
orginalScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("Language").Value = "2" Then
   'French
  Set jsheet = TemplateFR
Else
   'english
   Set jsheet = TemplateEN
End If

jsheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
'jSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

'Delete this line
jsheet.Unprotect jWorksheetPassword

Set jBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
jsheet.Copy After:=jBook.Sheets(1)
jBook.Sheets(2).Visible = xlSheetVisible

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
jBook.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

jsheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

'Delete this line
jBook.Sheets(1).Unprotect jWorksheetPassword
'Delete this line
'jsheet.Protect Password:=jWorksheetPassword

NoErrEnd:
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Protect Password:=jWorksheetPassword, Structure:=True, Windows:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = orginalScreenUpdating
Unload Me
Exit Sub

ErrEnd:
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Protect Password:=jWorksheetPassword, Structure:=True, Windows:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox DataTable.Range("MSG4").Value, vbCritical,    DataTable.Range("MSG4TITLE").Value
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines of code activate the original workbook and this somehow clears the protection of the copied sheet with excel 2013 only. On Excel 2007 this causes the original workbook to be activated and confuses users, hence the check for 2013.

```
If Application.Version = "15.0" Then
    Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Activate
    'jBook.Activate
End If
```

This is a hack that happens to work. If some one finds a better solution please do post it here as well.

The full code listing is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmd_Click()
Dim jBook As Workbook
Dim jsheet As Worksheet

CurrentWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Unprotect jWorksheetPassword
'catch all for errors
On Error GoTo ErrEnd
Dim orginalScreenUpdating As Boolean
orginalScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("Language").Value = "2" Then
    'French
    Set jsheet = TemplateFR
Else
    'english
    Set jsheet = TemplateEN
End If

jsheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Set jBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
jsheet.Copy After:=jBook.Sheets(1)
jBook.Sheets(2).Visible = xlSheetVisible

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
jBook.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Application.Version = "15.0" Then
    Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Activate
    'jBook.Activate
End If

jsheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

NoErrEnd:
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Protect Password:=jWorksheetPassword, Structure:=True, Windows:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = orginalScreenUpdating
Unload Me
Exit Sub

ErrEnd:
Workbooks(CurrentWorkBook).Protect Password:=jWorksheetPassword,     Structure:=True, Windows:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox DataTable.Range("MSG4").Value, vbCritical,     DataTable.Range("MSG4TITLE").Value
Unload Me


End Sub
```